# Looping through each item in a numpy array?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to access each item in a numpy 2D array.

I'm used to something like this in Python [[...], [...], [...]]

```
for row in data:
    for col in data:
       print(data[row][col])
```

but now, I have a `data_array = np.array(features)`

How can I iterate through it the same way?

Comment: We need a lot more detail in order to help.

Comment: Isn't this covered in the basic numpy documentation?

Comment: You can iterate through it in the same way by iterating through it in the same way. Try it and see! However, iterating through a 2D array completely defeats the point of using numpy, i.e. efficient array operations. Read [this doc page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/whatisnumpy.html), for instance.

Comment: Note that your current syntax is not correct, even for iterating through nested lists. You should rather be using `for row in data: for elem in row: print(elem)`. This would work for both nested lists and 2D arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a small 2d array, and a nested list from it:

```
In [241]: A=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [242]: alist= A.tolist()
In [243]: alist
Out[243]: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

One way of iterating on the list:

```
In [244]: for row in alist:
     ...:     for item in row:
     ...:         print(item)
     ...:         
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

works just same for the array

```
In [245]: for row in A:
     ...:     for item in row:
     ...:         print(item)
     ...:         
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now neither is good if you want to modify elements.  But for crude iteration over all elements this works.

WIth the array I can easily treat it was a 1d

```
In [246]: [i for i in A.flat]
Out[246]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I could also iterate with nested indices

```
In [247]: [A[i,j] for i in range(A.shape[0]) for j in range(A.shape[1])]
Out[247]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In general it is better to work with arrays without iteration.  I give these iteration examples to clearup some confusion.

Answer (score 8):

Try `np.ndenumerate`:

```
>>> a =numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> for (i,j), value in np.ndenumerate(a):
...  print(i, j, value)
... 
0 0 1
0 1 2 
1 0 3
1 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an item in a numpy 2D array features, you can use features[row_index, column_index]. If you wanted to iterate through a numpy array, you could just modify your script to

```
for row in data:

    for col in data:

       print(data[row, col])
```

Comment: No.  if you iterate like this, `row` is a 1d array.  You can use that as an index for `data`.  And the 2nd iteration is just the same.  You probably had `for item in row:` in mind.

Comment: What you need is `for row in data.shape[0]` and `for col in data.shape[1]`, or alternatively, `for row in data: for col in row: print(col)`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I forgot to change the for loop to use the numbers of rows and columns like Praveen did.